# Compact-cameras tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wikis

The current [compact-cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compact-cameras) tag is defined like this:

> Also called "Point and Shoot" cameras, they mostly have automatic
>   controls with a builtin flash

I belive this covers just a subset of them. There are also pretty advanced compact cameras that IMO don't belong into that category.
"Point and Shoot" is rather a mode of operation called "AUTO", found also in most DSLRs.

The tag definition should be changed.

EDIT: Looks like I can [improve tag wiki](https://photo.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1302). Could you propose a better definition?

Comment: The excerpt should define more about how the tag should be used, rather than just a description of what the tag describes